# PHPSESSID null on a specific page

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I have a problem that I am just done destroying my brain over.  I need someone to double check to make sure I am not missing something stupid simple.

So the problem is that for some reason I am having issues getting PHP sessions to work on a specific page on a website.  They work fine on every other page, and their grandma's pages, on the site but this specific page is not playing ball.

I have looked at it from every possible way I can think of.  I am using session_start() on the page, in fact it is set up like the ones that work.  I include a file called login_functions.php on every page, the first line in it is session_start().  I have tried checking for errors on the page, nothing.  I have tried outputting the $_Session var, it is empty even though on any other page it has all of the user information the site needs to execute some of the functionality.

I even set up some code to create a counter parameter in the session and then to increment it, that did not work either; it always stays 0 on the page in question.

I will link to the pages I set up the test counters on below with the php code from both of them.  If you request, I can set up a guest account so you can also see the session parameter issues between the two pages as well.

Page that works: https://sseminars.logopediaspeechtherapy.com/sdescrips.php

```
<?php
    if(!session_start()){
        echo "error, session status: ".session_status()."<br/>";    
    }

    require('php/login_functions.php');
    include_once 'php/cart_functions.php';

    if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Refreshed ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">refresh</a>";  

    if (!session_id()){
        $logged_in = false; 
    } else{
        if(checkLogin($_SESSION['Username']) == 1){
            $logged_in = true;
        } else {
            $logged_in = false; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Angsty page: https://sseminars.logopediaspeechtherapy.com/sfront.php

```
<?php
    if(!session_start()){
        echo "error, session status: ".session_status()."<br/>";    
    }
    require('php/login_functions.php');
    include 'php/cart_functions.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Refreshed ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">refresh</a>"; 


    if (!session_id()){
        $logged_in = false; 
    } else{
        if(checkLogin($_SESSION['Username']) == 1){
            $logged_in = true;
        } else {
            $logged_in = false; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my session info from PhpInfo:

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly 0   0
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /xd1/homes/hash/17/13/a11317/96/58/u105896/sseminars.logopediaspeechtherapy.com/tmp /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  4   4
session.sid_length  32  32
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1   1
session.use_only_cookies    1   1
session.use_strict_mode 0   0
session.use_trans_sid   1   1
```

PHP version is 7.2.15

Please let me know if you need any other code or information.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a space or any character before the first `<?php` opening tag, in sfront.php? Also please try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your script (before `session_start()`).

Comment: @Jeto That was going to be my last resort fix, to just try and redo the page which I have done and it is working now.  I have no clue what happened to it; maybe at some point an editor I used to modify it screwed around with the encoding and it threw an invisible character in?  Dunno, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what happened to it but some how maybe the file encoding got messed up or some editor threw in an invisible character.  I created a new file, type in the PHP again by hand and then copied the page code over.  It is working now.